# Roll up field always shows count as ZERO

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

**Goal:**

> Calculate the number of entities related to an entity using [roll up field](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832162.aspx)

In our [Dynamics 365](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365) online instance, We've implemented **1:N** relationship between the out of box `Project` entity and custom entity `Activity entry`.

[image: 1ActivityEntryMProject]

On the `Project` form, we've added a roll-up field named **Total Activities**:

[image: roll-up field]

And the conditions are properly set:

[image: roll-up field conditions]

The `Project` looks perfectly related to the `Activity Entry`

[image: Project is associated with Activity Entry]

The form shall at least show 1 in the field. Because, there is one `Project` assigned to one `Activity entry`.

[image: Total activities]

However on the main `Project` form, the count is always **0** only.

Answer (score 1):

Rollup fields are calculated from background processes (workflows) so it might take some time to be displayed there. You should see some Mass Calculation jobs there. Also try clicking on the calculator icon you had in the screenshot, that should force the calculation. If it is still 0 after that, there might be something wrong in the rollup field definition.

Comment: I've applied the configuration, do you see any problem anywhere?

Comment: Could you double check the Background processes of the associated Project record. Are there any? Are you sure you're using the right relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The default The default maximum recurrence setting for Rollup Fields is one hour. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832162.aspx

If you want to trigger them on demand you use CalculateRollupFieldRequest and CalculateRollupFieldResponse which is a synchronous operation for just the attribute identified in the request.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817863.aspx